# How to get the total number of subscribers in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I'm using NServiceBus and I need to know how many clients are subscribed to a specific message type (even better the names of the subscribers). I'm talking in a pub\sub scenario.

Is it possible to get this information in NServiceBus?

Thx

Comment: Do you need this for monitoring purposes or because of business demands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull this right out of your subscription storage.  Either a query to the database or a .GetAllMessages() on the queue will get you a count and the subscribers address.  If you are looking to do this in code, you could write a handler for the subscription message and count them up that way.

Comment: I need to know at some point in time how many subscribers exists. Which type of messages should I be handling in the handler?

Answer (score 1):

I have used ISubscriptionStorage with success.

```
public class SubscribersForMessageHandler :
             IHandleMessages<SubscribersForMessageRequest>
{
    public ISubscriptionStorage Storage { get; set; }
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(SubscribersForMessageRequest message)
    {
        Bus.Reply<SubscribersForMessageResponse>(m=>
        {
            m.SagaId = message.SagaId;
            m.MessageType = message.MessageType;
            m.SubscriberEndpoints = GetSubscribersForMessage(message.MessageType);
        });
    }

    private List<string> GetSubscribersForMessage(string type)
    {
        return Storage.GetSubscribersForMessage(
          new List<string> { type }).ToList();
    }
}
```